# image array creating unwanted image in top corner

Tags: arrays, image, lua, coronasdk

I have this set up in my main.lua file

```
images = {
   display.newImageRect("images/player3.png", 45,35),
   display.newImageRect("images/player4.png", 45,35),
   display.newImageRect("images/player5.png", 45,35)
}
```

and call it from my game.lua file with this code:

```
bird = images[math.random(1,3)]
bird.x, bird.y = -80, 140       
bird.name = "bird"
physics.addBody( bird, "static")
bird.isFixedRotation = true
birdIntro = transition.to(bird,{time=1000, x=100, onComplete= birdReady})
```

A random image spawns (where it should, in the middle) but the issue is that a second image spawns and sits in the top left corner of the screen (slightly off screen). I can't seem to remove it and keep the one correct image only, any solutions?

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is your images array.  I've found by calling the display.newImageRect it will create the object and plop it on the screen.  Even if you don't want it to show the object right then.  Usually I see this when I should be putting it in a display group (not sure if you are doing that).

I think the solution might be to have the array of images be the image paths and then you can set `bird` equal to a new image rect at that point, thus only creating 1 image rectangle instead of 3.

```
images = {
   "images/player3.png",
   "images/player4.png",
   "images/player5.png",
}

bird = display.newImageRect(images[math.random(1,3)],45,35)
```

Let me know if that works.

Comment: That worked great and fixed the issue, thanks Fernker for the help.